# Unable to add jsch-0.1.55.jar to existing Eclipse java project

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, jsch

I downloaded jsch-0.1.55.jar from https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsch/files/jsch.jar/0.1.55/jsch-0.1.55.jar/download, copied the JAR file into my lib directory, running Eclipse Version: 2023-12 (4.30.0) on Windows.  I attempted to add the JAR to the Eclipse by using Project Explorer->Right mouse click on project->Build Path->Configure Build Path->Java Build Path->Libraries Tab->Modulepath->Add JARs...->went to the lib folder I copied the JAR file to, but it's now showing, double checked it's in the lib folder via Windows Explorer and it is.  Tried adding it via Modulepath->"Add External JARs...", which it does add but it never shows up in Project Explorer under the lib folder, though it does show in Referenced Libraries, but when I try to do an import within the class I need it "import com.jcraft.jsch.*;", I get the error, "The package com.jcraft.jsch is not accessible".  I tried adding it to my module-info.java file "requires com.jcraft.jsch;", but I get the error, "com.jcraft.jsch cannot be resolved to a module".

Any help would be appreciated and no, I'm not using maven on this project.

Comment: Were you *intending* to use Java modules for your project?

Comment: `jsch-0.1.55.jar` has neither a `module-info.class` nor an `Automatic-Module-Name` which means the module name will be derived from the file name of the JAR and `requires com.jcraft.jsch;` is wrong. Consider just to delete your `module-info.java` file (if needed you can recreate it later via right-click on project and _Configure_).

Comment: @howlger Based on your comment I was able to find out how to add it by using the filename as my requires in module-info.java, i.e. "requires jsch;"  If you answer the question with this solution I'll mark it as answered.  Thank you!

Comment: @nitind I need a module-info.java file so it compiles, I'm fairly new to Java so not sure why everything is needed where, but this is what the template created for me in Eclipse.

Comment: See my answer below. The _New Java Project_ dialog has an option to create the `module-info.java` file which is enabled by default. `module-info.java` is required when using `jlink`. But there are use cases where you want to run and stop modules at runtime which is not supported by [JPMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System) in contrast to e.g. OSGi. In most cases you can choose whether you want encapsulation which requires a bit more work for maintaining the  `module-info.java`. In a nutshell, `module-info.java` is optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jsch-0.1.55.jar` has neither a `module-info.class` nor an `Automatic-Module-Name` in its `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`. So the module name will be derived from the file name of the JAR.

In your `module-info.java` file, replace

```
requires com.jcraft.jsch;
```

with

```
requires jcraft;
```

Alternatively, you can delete your `module-info.java` file (if needed you can recreate it later via right-click on the project and choosing *Configure*).

Comment: When I try to delete the module-info.java and try to run it in Debug I get the following error:
`Error: Could not find or load main class main.mainGUI
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/net/telnet/TelnetNotificationHandler`
In my debug configuration I have the Main class set correctly, if I use the Search button it allows me to find it via the GUI so I'm assuming it's correct?

Comment: Does in _Run > Run Configurations..._ deleting the run/debug configuration and re-trying help? There might be an issue that Eclipse does not correctly update the launch configuration after deleting the `module-info.java` file.

Comment: yes, after deleing the Run Configurations, it will now compile, however, when I run my application I'm getting the error "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jcraft/jsch/JSchException", do you know how to resolve that?  As I'd prefer not to have to have a module-info.java file.

Comment: never mind.  I changed the Run Configuration for the JAR from being in my module path to being in the class path and it's now working.

Comment: I'm glad it's working now. Better do this (_"the JAR from being in my module path to being in the class path"_) in _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_, tab _Libraries_ rather than for each run configuration.